# sqlite compare timestamp with DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

How do I compare sqlite timestamp with C# `DateTime`? I have:

```
string query = string.Format(@"select avg(CPUH_VALUE_ALL) as Value from CPU_HOUR where CPUH_DATE >= @Date");
var pars = new List<SQLiteParameter>();
pars.Add(new SQLiteParameter("Date", DateTimeSQLite(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-12))));
```

where

```
static string DateTimeSQLite(DateTime datetime)
{
    string dateTimeFormat = "{0}-{1}-{2} {3}:{4}:{5}.{6}";
    return string.Format(dateTimeFormat, datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, datetime.Hour, datetime.Minute, datetime.Second, datetime.Millisecond);
}
```

That wouldn't work. And nothing works when I try compare timestamp with string value of date in various formats either. Any clues?

**Edit**

```
select CPUH_DATE from CPU_HOUR where CPUH_DATE
```

get me records like this:

```
5/19/2014 9:30:54 PM
```

**Edit2**
I've just discovered that while this is not working:

```
select * from CPU_HOUR where CPUH_DATE >= '2014-5-19 21:30:08'
```

this is (note the zero before 5):

```
select * from CPU_HOUR where CPUH_DATE >= '2014-05-19 21:30:08'
```

Interesting.

Comment: In what format you get the date when you select CPUH_DATE? Could you add it to the question description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
>   and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
>   are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
>   values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS"). REAL as Julian
>   day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November
>   24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar. INTEGER
>   as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>   Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these
>   formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and
>   time functions.

Source: [sqllite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

My suggestion would be to just save the datetime values as integer. This way you will have no problems with operations such as comparision. And if you ever need non-numeric date in your query, you can use built in Datetime function like this:

```
SELECT datetime(1092941466, 'unixepoch');
```

Comment: Just in case someone out there is looking to convert a DateTime generated by .Net code (stored in SQLite as bigint):   
  
`select datetime(lastModified/10000000 - 62135596800, 'unixepoch')
from YourTable`  
  
More here: [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54282/sqlite-datetime-convert-to-net-datetime)

Comment: For the Developer using c# , please see Ryan Russon 's answer. 
As for my case I'm using SQLite-net  in Xamarin project , this library has  build-in method to create table in sqllite DB ( my auto generated table has DateTime field.). When query the statement  "Date(mycolumnDatetime)" will got null value !